# HTML5 History - Back button to previous full page?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I'm using the HTML5 history API to modify the URL as certain product properties are selected (e.g. green car, blue car) to allow for deep-link sharing.

However, this isn't a single page app, so I don't want to hijack the user's back button: if they press back, I want to allow them to go to the previous page, not the previous car color.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Example history:

```
/page1
/page2
/page2?color=green
/page2?color=red
/page2?color=blue
```

Then press the browser's back button to go back to `/page1`

Comment: Don't use a back at all. Simply do a forward action to the last page. You could use sessionStorage or localStorage to store the last page visited and check for changes in each page.

Comment: I like the idea, but like I mentioned in the question, I want people to be able to use their browser's back button (or Android's back nav button) to go to the previous page. Is that something that I can take over through JS?

Comment: No, and you should not do so, even if you could. You would be breaking the browser's back button functionality and user expectations. If you want to give them an option to go to a previous page, then you can expose that, but you can't break browser functionality with such a potentially malicious bit of scripting.

Comment: Right, exactly. So unfortunately the solution you presented doesn't work for me. Thanks though!

Comment: You can give this functionality in the browser for your application via a button/link on your page, using a technique similar to my suggestion above, but you cannot break back button functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I should have been using

```
history.replaceState();
```

instead of `history.pushState();`. It replaces the browser's URL, but doesn't add to the history object, so the back button works as I want it to.

> history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using sessionStorage that gives your application the ability to go to a previously stored page, without breaking usability expectations/browser back button functionality. Moving to a previous URL (e.g. different color) is the expected result of using the back button on the browser for the user.

**JS**

```
function getCurrentPath() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem("currentPath");
}

function getPreviousPath() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem("previousPath");
}

function setCurrentPath(path) {
    var currentPath = getCurrentPath();
    if (currentPath != path) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("previousPath", currentPath);
        sessionStorage.setItem("currentPath", path);
    } else {
        console.log('Path has not changed: ' + path);
    }
}

function goToPrevious() {
    var previousPath = getPreviousPath();
    if (previousPath && previousPath != 'null') {
        window.location.href = previousPath;
    } else {
        alert('Previous page is not defined.');
    }
}
```

**test1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="test.js"></script>
        <script>
            setCurrentPath('test1.html');
            console.log('Current Path:', getCurrentPath());
            console.log('Previous Path:', getPreviousPath());
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="goToPrevious();">Go to previous page</button>
        <a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>
        <a href="?color=red">Red</a>
        <a href="?color=green">Green</a>
        <a href="?color=blue">Blue</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="test.js"></script>
        <script>
            setCurrentPath('test2.html');
            console.log('Current Path:', getCurrentPath());
            console.log('Previous Path:', getPreviousPath());
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="goToPrevious();">Go to previous page</button>
        <a href="test1.html">Test 1</a>
        <a href="?color=red">Red</a>
        <a href="?color=green">Green</a>
        <a href="?color=blue">Blue</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that this allows the user to change query string parameters, but this does not affect your functionality for moving to a previous page through a forward action, simply by storing changes between paths. You could extend this by using an array rather than simply two values like I've done here, but I'll leave that up to implement, should you wish to do so.